# Get Aggregated Counts in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb Table that stores scheduled Jobs data with its ID and Status values (Initiated, Started, In Progress, Completed, Failed). Now I want to query the data like Total Jobs count and also count of each status value. What is the best way to get this data from Dynamodb Table?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the counts using Dynamodb Streams with lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a RDBMS, DDB doesn't have a COUNT or any other aggregation functions...so the the only way to get a count is to Query() or Scan() your data, returning that data to your application and counting the rows yourself.

Best practice if you need aggregates, is to configure a DDB stream to a lambda that will update another DDB table (or a row in the table in question) with the record count and any other aggregate info you want to track. A GSI is often useful here as discussed in [Using Global Secondary Indexes for Materialized Aggregation Queries.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html)